# item[ID] doesn't return item[ID]

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, splistitem

I have a peculiar issue, following is the code :

```
var item = list.Items[ID];
```

The problem is that the returned item is actually the `Items[ID-11]`.
I can verify that from `dispitem.aspx?id=[ID]`

Since the items start with ID = 11 (some items have deleted), it looks like the ID is actually a counter and not item's ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

get the item in SPlistitem and then get value from it. 
For ex =

```
Splistitem item = list.getitembyid(1);
var x = item.ID;
```

Answer (score 6):

In SharePoint ID is a counter and always incremental. Even though you delete item, it is never going to occupy the blank ID. It always keeps on incrementing.

Also `list.Items` always return `SPListItemCollection`. But when you delete the item from List, the index of Item keeps on changing. For example, you had 10 items in list `list.Items[9]` will give you the item with `ID = 10`. But if you delete two items lets say ID equals 5 & 6. Than `list.Items[9]` will throw an error, while `list.Items[7]` will give you item with `ID = 10`.

To get the item from `SPListItemCollection` using ID try the following code.

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("List title");
SPListItemCollection itemColl = list.Items;
SPListItem item = itemColl.GetItemById(id);
```

In this way you'll always get the item you require.

Answer (score 2):

`list.Items[ID];` (th variable named `ID` is probably not the best here to understand it, `index` would be better) is a pure C# syntax: that's an array indexer (zero-based).
It's used to access an in-memory collection of ordered objects. `[index]` has nothing to do with SharePoint, and when calling this code .NET we simply access an array of ordinary objects already populated into the array. It has no awareness of SharePoint at this time.
SharePoint did the actual SharePoint job (requesting the DB, etc.) when `.Items` was called the first time on this list. It got all the items of the list (mind the performances if you have more than ~10s items...) and populates the array. From there, the index in the array has nothing to do with the ID of the items.

As others mentioned, use `list.GetItemById(ID);` to retrieve a specific item whose ID is known. And this will give you much better results regarding performances (only one item retrieved from SQL and loaded into memory).